# Is there a way to use socket library securely

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

guys, I am looking for a way to connect my python socket programms **securely**.
I imagined something like the following:

```py
from socket import *
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, cert="cetificate.pem")
server.bind(("192.168.2.100",8080))
server.listen()
while True:
  client, addr = socket.accept()
  client.sendall(b"Hello, World!")
```

I have found an alternative solution on github, but it is very complex and i dont understand it.
Please help me guys

Comment: The low-level `socket` library simply sends and receiver individual bytes over the network. You seem to be looking for a higher-level application layer protocol with encryption. Probably look at TLS or SSH, or specify in more detail how they are unsuitable.

Comment: Thanks, i will try those ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```py
import socket
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('/path/to/certchain.pem', '/path/to/private.key')

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8443))
    sock.listen(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
        conn, addr = ssock.accept()
```